# Get grammar from his LALR(1) parsing table

Tags: parsing, context-free-grammar, lalr

I have a problem with this exercise. This is the LALR(1) parsing table for the grammar G. How can i get the productions of G?

[LALR(1) parsing table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hier1.png)

Thanks :)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Note that this is a Q&A site and not a code writing service. See also [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: One thing that might help you would be to draw the state transition diagram.

Comment: Thank you for the comment! Yeah I already did it but doesn't help :( It's a tricky parse table because is LARL and there are shift/reduce conflict!